# Help with ambiguous notation

Tags: probability, notation

I am reading  [Probabilistic and Graphical Models](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/probabilistic-graphical-models), and uncertain about the meaning of the following use of the notation $\mathbf{I}$. The textbook defines the use of $\mathbf{I}$ to mean flow of information, but that function appears to require two arguments. My guess is that she means Iverson brackets, but I want to verify and ask, what does she mean in the following sentence

*More generally, we might want to estimate the expectation of some function $f(\mathcal{X})$ relative to $P$; this task is a generalization, since we can choose $f(\xi) = \mathbf{I}\{\xi\langle\mathbf{Y}\rangle  = \mathbf y\}$*

Attached is a screen capture of the paragraph.
[image]

---

The $\mathbf{I}$ may in fact stand for a random variable.

Comment: You want "\mathcal{X}", "\xi", "\langle", and "\rangle".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\mathbf{I}$ means indicator function of a random variable. See pg. 490. The book has a notation index, but I didn't see it in there.